# Help potatos growing?

Tags: compost, potatoes

I think i have potato plants growing in my compose box . which would be a first for me. And i am unsure if that is what they are and how to cross plant them to a new location.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't grow potatoes in your garden last year, most likely these have come from kitchen waste. The fact that they are growing at all suggests your compost box isn't working very well and not getting hot enough to kill seeds etc.

Personally I would just pull them up and dispose of them in your household waste. Potatoes, like other *Solanaceae* such as tomatoes, are very susceptible to virus infections, and you don't want to pollute your garden with diseases that can survive in the soil for years and cause problems with future crops.

Comment: Ummmm.. .. We necer planted anything yet in garden per say. We have a box divided up into thirds, 1 ( stage 1) half compose.  There other 2 parts are set up for 1part to be 2 stage of compose . 3 part is set up for plants.  Last year we got a hugh tomato plant that grow up for scraps, we cross planted it and got the best tasting tomatos all summer